# what makes this image manipulation useful [accelerated C++]

Tags: c++

I am going through *Accelerated C++* and question 5-5 asks:

> 5-5. Write a function named `center(const vector<string>&)` that returns a picture in which all the lines of the original picture are padded out to their full width, and the padding is as evenly divided as possible between the left and right sides of the picture. **What are the properties of pictures for which such a function is useful?** How can you tell whether a given picture has those properties?

Here is an image of the function input and then output:
http://i1296.photobucket.com/albums/ag7/David_Jhoo/Untitled_zps9f0e32b4.png

I'm pretty puzzled as to why this would be useful.  At first I was thinking image compression, for the inverse function, but we would have to make the square smaller for that.  I feel like it would just make any real image look weird. Any thoughts?

Comment: While the text refers to the item as a picture, the function takes a set of strings.  So should you be thinking of the answer in terms of text or pixels?

Comment: That picture looks just like you're centering text. That's also impled by the function signature. I can't see anything relating to images or image processing.

Comment: I think we're using "picture" in the COBOL sense here.

Comment: @hobbs Surely you're far too young to know COBOL ;-) I thought it was only for old geeks like me ...

Comment: @RogerRowland ha, not in depth, but I do take an interest in old & sometimes obscure things.

Comment: @hobbs Having many years practical experience of 4 different COBOL flavours, *"old and obscure"* is making me feel very useful. ROFL

Comment: Oh. I guess I figured it had some relation to image processing since he calls them 'pictures'.  But, ya that's all I can see also.  Thanks

Comment: @RogerRowland I didn't mean it quite that way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems clear to me that when the book talks about "pictures" it doesn't mean images in the usual sense; it means a two-dimensional arrangement of characters — or basically, just a list of strings.

To answer the book's question (which I think is a silly one), the only useful input properties that I can think of are that the strings don't already have leading or trailing spaces, and that at least some of them are at least two characters shorter than the maximum width so that they can be properly centered.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.  Andrew Koenig (author) mentioned bit-map graphics, so maybe there is some use there? `A character picture is a rectangular array of characters that can be
displayed. It is a simplification of what happens in a real application—in this case, applications
based on bitmap graphics.`

Comment: @DavidJhoo yeah, there are clearly similarities. But I don't know what the author has in mind if he's imagining that this is useful for images somehow :)

Comment: Hah. Thanks. I've been scratching my head this whole time...

Comment: bitmapped graphics makes sense.  Because a std::string can contain any ascii value from 0 to 256, if the display is memory mapped 8-bit pixels then each character in the string *IS* a pixel.  I've done that before with VGA mode 0x13.  An arrany of strings *IS* an array of pixels in that case.